# SimpleLightBox wont run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am unable to run SimpleLightBox (after click on image it opens as regular image on blank page) from this link http://dbrekalo.github.io/simpleLightbox/ . But i have problem. I added JS and CSS file (correctly i can open it in source code). Then i added HTML and JS in code.

```
  <div class="imageGallery1">
    <a href="images/5x5.jpg" title="Caption for gallery item 1" ><img style="width: 300px; height: 300px" src="images/5x5.jpg" alt="Gallery image 1"/></a>
    <a href="images/BG-BR5.jpg" title="Caption for gallery item 2"><img style="width: 300px; height: 300px" src="images/BG-BR5.jpg" alt="Gallery image 2" /></a>
    <a href="images/BG-BR6.jpg" title="Caption for gallery item 3"><img style="width: 300px; height: 300px"src="images/BG-BR6.jpg" alt="Gallery image 3" /></a>    
</div>
<script>$('.imageGallery1 a').simpleLightbox();</script>
```

Images are inserted correctly and i have jquery too because i am using bootstrap 4. Here is link with template i am working on https://vitas.sk/1/ (scroll down).

Comment: place your lighbox script after jquery and bootstrap scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I check your template page I noticed the error in the console

> "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

Then I investigated your code and noticed that you are calling the SimpleLightBox plugin in the `<head>`, while the jquery library is called at the end of the page (just before the `</body>` tag).

What is happening is that the SimpleLightBox plugin is getting executed before the jQuery library is initialized.

Do the following to fix the issue:

1) This will fix the library being initialized after jQuery is loaded.
Put the following line before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="js/simpleLightbox.js" ></script>
```

2) This will fix the method being executed after the simpleLightBox Plugin is loaded.
Move the following code (and add the ready function) after the line above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imageGallery1 a').simpleLightbox();
});
```

I have added the `$(document).ready();` around the code to make sure the code gets executed when the whole page and its scripts is done loading.

Comment: What help is adding jquery on beginning of document (in head) but i want to have both scripts at the end and dont know how to do this. (your solution is not working)

Comment: Yes but adding simplelightbox script before end of body tag is not working only at beginning and i dont know why. I done what you say look at website  https://vitas.sk/1/ but its not working.

Comment: What is currently happening: the $('.imageGallery1 a').simpleLightbox(); is geting exectured before the plugins are loaded... I will update by answer:

Comment: I never used JS before. But i changed that Js script as you said. https://vitas.sk/1/ adn its not working. Where exactly should i put - ( would advice to add the $(document).ready(); around the code to make sure the code gets executed when the whole page and its scripts is done loading.)

Comment: I see that you have put the code of step 2 before the code of step 1. Putting this code after the <script src="js/simpleLightbox.js" ></script> should fix the issue